# Java JSF navigation URL Issue?

Tags: java, jsf

Ok the following code is what I have in a drop down menu on my facelets to visit different pages.

```
 <p:toolbarGroup align="right">  
            <p:menuButton value="Navigate">  
                <p:menuitem value="Home" url="index.xhtml" />  
                <p:menuitem value="Reservation Form"  
                            url="form.xhtml" />  
                <p:menuitem value="Pending Requests"  
                            url="pending.xhtml" />  
            </p:menuButton>  
        </p:toolbarGroup>  

      </p:toolbar>
```

Now the issue is, sometimes and I emphasize sometimes when I press on a link to another page, it goes there but the URL address in the bar doesn't change. so it says index.xhtml example when am looking at form.xhtml.

Another thing i noticed was the auto-complete issue. So sometimes the auto-complete in the form page would load all the entries I had before and other times it doesn't even though it is same page. All these indicate that the page is treated differently here in two occasions. So When I submit the form, sometimes it works and other times it just fails (at FacesContext dispatch part) although the data is actually stored correctly in DB. Ay ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, add `ajax="false"` on each `<p:menuitem>` so that the browser does not use an ajax request to load the specified page.

```
<p:toolbarGroup align="right">  
    <p:menuButton value="Navigate">  
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="index.xhtml" ajax="false" />
        <p:menuitem value="Reservation Form" url="form.xhtml" ajax="false" />
        <p:menuitem value="Pending Requests" url="pending.xhtml" ajax="false" />
    </p:menuButton>  
</p:toolbarGroup>
```

Comment: hmmm ok will do. should have really because I read that some issues occur with events due to that.

Comment: I beg your pardon? The second sentence does not many any sense.

Comment: Sorry meant that I should have set it to false. I read somewhere during my search in the questions here that if not set to false, it triggers a UI event or something like that. Hence it should be over-riden. I clearly have no good knowledge of the matter